# how to authenticate domain credential in powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script which validate multiple tests in each windows image. But the below specific test require domain credentials to be used to run successfully when I use this script!

Can anyone help me to fix ?

```
if (($ImageName -like "*dev*") -or ($ImageName -like "*bare*"))
    {
        #$ADE1 = Invoke-Expression ('C:\ade\bin\ade.exe | select-string -pattern "begintrans"') | out-string ; $ADE = $ADE1.trim().split("")[1]
        Invoke-Expression ('C:\ade\bin\ade.exe | select-string -pattern "begintrans"') > C:\Temp\ade_check.txt 
        $ADE1 = Get-Content C:\Temp\ade_check.txt | Select-String "begintrans" | out-string ;  $ADE = $ADE1.trim().split(" ")[1]

        if ($ADE -eq "begintrans")
        {
        $ADE = "ADE Success"
echo "ADE = ADE Success"
        }

        if ($ADE -eq $null){
        $ADE = "ADE Failed"
echo "ADE = ADE Failed"
        }

    }
    else
        {
        if (($ImageName -like "*simple*") -or ($ImageName -like "*BareOS*")){

        $ADE = "BareOS, ADE Not Installed"
echo "ADE = BareOS, ADE Not Installed"
        }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried [`Get-Credential`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential) yet?

Comment: this ask username and password . I want the script to be run remotely using Jenkins tool. So it shouldn't ask username and password.    Is there anyway so that we can add user name and password in the script to do the same

Comment: Yes, there is a way for saving credentials and passing those forward. The question omits this critical piece of information. First you ask about credentials. You are hinted for cmdlet. Then you reveal that it's being run on remote system. What's next?

Comment: Note that many actions that require credentials (eg Copy-Item and Invoke-Command) will just plain refuse to work in a PSSession without a whole ton of configuring. So when you say you're running it remotely, is it in a PSSession, scheduled task, etc?

Comment: I am using a tool called Jenkins to run the script remotely. So the tool will take the script and run in each machine

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @vonPryz running the script in an authenticated remote session is probably the best thing to. Regarding your concern that `Get-Credential` is needed for instantiating a remote session and asks for username and password, there are at least two options:

1. Creating `PSCredential` on the fly
2. Reading encrypted credentials from disk

## Creating `PSCredential` on the fly

Creating credentials from clear text passwords is described here: 
[Creating a PS Credential from a Clear Text Password in Powershell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/gary/2009/07/23/creating-a-ps-credential-from-a-clear-text-password-in-powershell/)

You basically run:

```
PS C:\> $password = "P@ssw0rd" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
PS C:\> $username = "EdgarSchnittenfittich" 
PS C:\> $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
```

## Reading encrypted credentials from disk

Once you have a `PSCredential` object you can export it in an encrypted form via `Export-CliXml`. To import your credentials just issue `Import-CliXml`. The credentials are store in an encrypted form with an opaque encryption key for the *current* user exporting the credentials. This means that only the same user can later on import the credentials again.

Example:

```
$cred = Get-PSCredential;
$cred | Export-CliXml C:\TEMP\Credentials.xml;

$importedCredentials = Import-CliXml C:\TEMP\Credentials.xml;
```

## Running your Scripts

- With these credentials you can easily run any script via `Enter-PSSession` or `Invoke-Command`.
- Regarding your Jenkins environment: make sure you export the encrypted credentials under the same service account that you use to import your credentials.